# django-allauth email verification: works for @gmail test account but not @yahoo?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

This is pretty weird to me.  For a while I thought the account verification was not working.  I was testing it with an @yahoo.com email address.

Then I decided to test it with an @gmail.com email address.

I have tested both accounts multiple times and am certain I do not have a typo in the @yahoo.com email.

How is this even possible?  It doesn't make sense to me but if someone can shed some light on the issue I would really appreciate it.  Obviously this will not fly.

Thanks.  Django 1.11, Python 3, and latest AllAuth.

```
#AllAuth Settings
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
#ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Comment: May be an issue with your email service. What do you use? Your IP may be blocked by yahoo

Comment: SendGrid.  I guess the move is to test SendGrid in the shell with the yahoo email receiving.

Comment: Sendgrid should have a dashboard where I would guess you can see if the email was sent. But these providers are known to get you into blacklists